# Writing One Method For Testing Multiple Browsers

Tags: eclipse, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have WebDriver and am using Java. 
In C# with WatiN I was able to write something like this:
Method

Browser browser = new Browser()
This is where what I would do with the browser would go. Like navigating to the URL

Then I would create a test method and actually define the browser
[TestMethod]
 Method_IE
Method(new IE());

Is there anyway to do something like this in Eclipse with WebDriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We came up with something pretty simple for use in the page object model.

```
public WebDriver GetDriver(String driver, String url){

    WebDriver driver;  

    if( driver == 'firefox'){
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    else if(driver == 'chrome'){
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(driver == 'ie'){
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    driver.get(url); 
    return driver
}
```

Your IDE shouldnt matter at all as long as you specify the class in your source.

Comment: I would however I need more rep.